# Uso del artículo definido

Tags: artículos

> > "A la izquierda de la fotografía, hay _ montañas."

Este frase es de Josefa Martín García.

¿Por qué no inserta el artículo definido en el espacio? 
Crea una generalización en esta frase, así que creo que debe usar el artículo definido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu pregunta no se refiere tanto al uso del artículo como al uso del verbo **haber**, en este caso la palabra "hay".

Se trata de una estructura fija muy frecuente, encabezada por alguna de estas formas verbales, según el tiempo:

> había, hubo, hay, habrá, va a haber

Lo que viene después del verbo es una frase nominal que funciona como complemento directo.

> Hay **cuatro hombres** en la puerta.
>
> Va a haber **una reunión** el sábado.

El significado de esta estructura es: *el objeto mencionado existió, existe o existirá*.

Antes que nada, hay una regla, y hay que ser obedientes: *Si después de la palabra "hay" viene un artículo, éste debe ser indefinido*.

> Hay una reunión. [Correcto]
>
> Hay la reunión. [Incorrecto]

Y ahora la explicación:

Los artículos definidos (el, la...) acompañan sustantivos que ya son conocidos por los hablantes. Si tú dices "la montaña", te estás refiriendo a una montaña que tú y yo ya hemos identificado, una montaña distinta a todo el resto de las montañas, esa montaña, la montaña de la que estamos conversando.

Pero en las oraciones que comienzan con "hay" estamos haciendo una declaración de la existencia del sustantivo. Es decir, en esta oración estamos reconociendo por primera vez la existencia de ciertas montañas, para después seguir hablando de ellas:

> A la izquierda de la fotografía hay **unas** montañas. Son **las** montañas más bonitas que he visto en mi vida.

En la primera oración se presentan unas montañas, de las cuales no sabíamos nada (artículo indefinido). En la segunda oración hablamos específicamente de las montañas que ya identificamos en la oración anterior (artículo definido).

Comment: ¿ Es correcto decir " A la izquierda de la fotografía hay montañas"?

Comment: @AmandaKelius Sí, está bien dicho.

Answer (score 2):

El verbo *haber* no admite sustantivos definidos por las razones que ha indicado Rodrigo.  Cabe notar que la misma restricción existe en inglés aunque es difícil notarla porque, a pesar de usar las mismas palabras, al cambiar de indefinido a definido, estas palabras tienen funciones diferentes, evidentes al traducir al español:

- There are some mountains (*hay unas montañas*)
- There are the mountains (*allí están las montañas*)